# which time would i need use ( For loop in For loop ) in python programming language

Tags: python, list, for-loop

**I want to know that which moment in programming we'll go to need use type of this for loop ?**

```
number_grid = [
[1, 2, 3],
[4, 5, 6],
[7, 8, 9],
[0]
]

for row in number_grid:
    for col in row:
        print (col)
```

I was learning python programming, and in examples, I saw this code and I was wondered that would I need to code like this and need use `for loop in for loop` in programming with python?

Comment: The example answers itself -- you use it whenever you want to loop through a 2-dimensional set of data.

Comment: If you look for the term **"nested loop"** you should find plenty of tutorials for this.

Comment: An example might be a tic-tac-toe program. To check for a winner, you loop through the rows or columns, then loop through the cells in that row/column to check if they're all the ssame.

Comment: U gonna use that evertime u has a 2d list, to make a for each in each list from main list

Comment: @Barmar thanks for useful example, i'm watching a video for tic-tac-toe code programming to make sure that i undrestand how it works.

Comment: This is a common pattern when you have a group of things, and each thing also contains another group of things.  For example a list of classes, where each class contains a list of students.  Or a list of car manufacturers, where each manufacturer contains a list of models.

Answer (score 1):

Are you asking about when one would use nested `for` loops? I.e., a `for` loop inside another `for` loop? Typically that's done when you need to iterate over a so-called "2D" data structure, such as a list of lists (like `number_grid` here). The outer loop indexes into the outer list, and then the inner loop literates over each internal list.

Comment: so it's help to bring out every single data or numbers that we have in list in list?
it helps only for this ?

Comment: It make all things, that is how the language works

Comment: This pattern can be used wherever you need to iterate over two-dimensional data. Lists in lists is probably the most common application, however. I won't say it's *only* useful for this however. Nothing in programming is *only* useful for one thing.

Answer (score 0):

To complement what JRiggles say...
Its work like:

```
lists_values = [
    [1,2,3],
    [4,5,6]
]

for list_value in lists_values:
    # first -> list = [1,2,3]
    # second -> list = [4,5,6]
    for element_value in list_value:
        # first list -> element = 1
        # first list -> element = 2
        # first list -> element = 3
        # second list -> element = 4
        # second list -> element = 5
        # second list -> element = 6
        print(element_value)
```

that will print each element inside each list:

```
>>> 1
>>> 2
>>> 3
>>> 4
>>> 5
>>> 6
```

Answer (score 0):

As @JRiggles mentionned, "nested for loops" as they are called, are useful when you want to look through every element of a matrix, or a list within a list for example.

Say you are making a 2D board game, like chess. You could have a simple list storing what is on every square of your board, like so :

```py
board_state = [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 4, 3, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 10, 9, 8]
```

If you wanted to look at your list, you could now simply do:

```py
for piece in board_state:
    # do stuff
```

However you'll find you have trouble looking at a specific piece. You could always do it, but it's much easier to start with a two dimensional list from the get go :

```py
board_state = [
    [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 4, 3, 2],
    [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7],
    [8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 10, 9, 8]
```

Now, not only is it easy to see how this is a chess board, but you can easily do something with a specific piece with `board_state[y_coord][x_coord]` or, to answer the original question, you can use two for loops to go through every piece:

```py
for row in board_state:
    for cell in row:
        # do some thing
```